# Get URL values from <iframe> with different domain name

Tags: php, url, iframe, youtube

I used a form to capture data from clients. In this form is an iframe that loads youtube videos onto youtube. The reason for the different URL is because my original code was written in CakePHP and the youtube api uses the Zend Framework.

Now I need the values returned from youtube that is stored in the URL of the iframe to save in the DB, so that when called later the video will open with the correct listing.

Any advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to get any information about pages loaded into an iframe if the document loaded into it comes from a different domain. This is due to [the same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

YouTube has [an API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/getting_started#data_api) that allows people to perform searches of YouTube from your website. You could use that to allow people to select videos instead of trying to reverse engineer the YouTube URI system.

Comment: I have now loaded the whole iframe into the same domain. I have configured it to work. How can I get the URL values from the iframe now?